# JavaScript - "Filter" through an object - best practise?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What is the best way to "filter" through an object? I have an example object that looks like:

```
const response = {
       "example-feed": [
          {
             "money": {
                "amount": 2588
             },
             "sourcemoney": {
                "amount": 2588
             },
             "direction": "OUT"

          },
          {
             "money": {
                "amount": 2925
             },
             "sourcemoney": {
                "amount": 2925
             },
             "direction": "IN"

          },
          {
             "money": {
                "amount": 1921
             },
             "sourcemoney": {
                "amount": 1921
             },
             "direction": "OUT"
          },
          {
             "money": {
                "amount": 1467
             },
             "sourcemoney": {
                "amount": 1467
             },
             "direction": "IN"
          },
       ]
    }
```

What is the best way to "filter" through it to remove any objects that have the key-value pairing of `"direction": "IN"`?

For example, I would like to remove the two objects that have a direction set to IN, so the new object becomes:

```
const response = {
   "example-feed": [
      {
         "money": {
            "amount": 2588
         },
         "sourcemoney": {
            "amount": 2588
         },
         "direction": "OUT"

      },
      {
         "money": {
            "amount": 1921
         },
         "sourcemoney": {
            "amount": 1921
         },
         "direction": "OUT"
      },
   ]
}
```

Within an array, I know you can use the `filter` functionality? Curious to understand what the best practise is here to try and achieve the above?

Comment: do you have tried it yourself?

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: The `example-feed` property is an `array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to use methods which are designed to make filtering:

```
response['example-feed'] = response['example-feed'].filter(f => f.direction != 'IN');
```

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method works with arrays, so you need to filter array, not an object.

An example:

```js
const response = {
    "example-feed": [
       {
          "money": {
             "amount": 2588
          },
          "sourcemoney": {
             "amount": 2588
          },
          "direction": "OUT"

       },
       {
          "money": {
             "amount": 2925
          },
          "sourcemoney": {
             "amount": 2925
          },
          "direction": "IN"

       },
       {
          "money": {
             "amount": 1921
          },
          "sourcemoney": {
             "amount": 1921
          },
          "direction": "OUT"
       },
       {
          "money": {
             "amount": 1467
          },
          "sourcemoney": {
             "amount": 1467
          },
          "direction": "IN"
       },
    ]
 };

 response['example-feed'] = response['example-feed'].filter(f => f.direction != 
 'IN');
 console.log(response)
```

Comment: I agree, but will this work on an object? Whenever I try it, it mentions about not finding the `filter1 method?

Comment: @user3180997, you don't want to filter an object you want to filter a property on an object which is an array i.e response["example-feed"]

Comment: @user3180997 `filter` method works with arrays, so you need to filter array. not an object. Please, see my updated answer

Comment: Testing this now. Will get back as soon as possible, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const response={
   "example-feed": [
      {
         "money": {
            "amount": 2588
         },
         "sourcemoney": {
            "amount": 2588
         },
         "direction": "OUT"

      },
      {
         "money": {
            "amount": 2925
         },
         "sourcemoney": {
            "amount": 2925
         },
         "direction": "IN"

      },
      {
         "money": {
            "amount": 1921
         },
         "sourcemoney": {
            "amount": 1921
         },
         "direction": "OUT"
      },
      {
         "money": {
            "amount": 1467
         },
         "sourcemoney": {
            "amount": 1467
         },
         "direction": "IN"
      },
   ]
}

const filteredres=response['example-feed'].filter(obj=>
               obj.direction!=='IN'
)
console.log(filteredres)
```